# Define group G based on H and K

Tags: group-theory

Given groups $H$ and $K$, define a group $G$ based on $H$ and $K$ as $G:=\{(h,k):h\in H, k\in K\}$ such that

$$(h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2)=(h_1h_2,\phi(h_1,k_1,h_2,k_2))$$

Given $G$ is a well-defined group , what properties we can derive that $\phi$ must have?

Comment: "what kind of property $\phi$ must have " for what ? for $G$ to be a group ? Also, I think you want to write $(h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2)=(\phi(h_1,k_1,h_2,k_2), k_1k_2)$...

Comment: @GreginGre thanks for the comment, problem updated